# unable to load a UIImage in a UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, xcode4.2

I am developing an iOS app using XCode 4.2

I have a UIImage variable and I am trying to load it in a UIImageView by simply saying `imgView=image`

but I am getting an error saying :

```
expected identifier or '('
```

can someone please assist

thank you

Edited :

I tried the following code :

```
imgView.image=image;
```

I am getting this error :

```
Property 'image' not found on object  of type 'imgView'
```

Comment: more code please. also try imgView.image = img

Comment: This is a compilation error.  Xcode will give you a list of errors and warning, and the associated file / line.  Go to the code associated with this error and review the statement for a problem with the Objective C syntax and/or an error in how you've used the UIImageView API.

Comment: xlc0212 : I edited my question

Comment: In future I recommend you to read the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/)

Comment: Snips : I don t understand what you are saying exactly , please rephrase

Comment: Can you post the code you use to declare `imgView`. It is probably not a `UIImageView`.

Comment: I found the issue , I had the name of the class and the variable the same!!! , so imageview.image=image works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the image of an UIImageView like this:

```
imageView.image = image;
```

Edit: Here is a more detailed example:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:"@image.png"]; // Change "image.png" by the name of your image file
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; // frame is a CGRect.
imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: I edited my code , still no working , check my edited question

Comment: I found the issue , I had the name of the class and the variable the same!!! , so imageview.image=image works!